# Angularjs/Ionic DB result with promise

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple query that I am struggling with:

```
.factory('Config', function($http, DB) {
  var self = this;
  self.setValue = function(key,value) {
    console.log('setValue(value)', value);
    return DB.query("UPDATE config SET value = '"+value+"' WHERE key = '"+key+"'")
    .then(function(result){
              return DB.fetchAll(result);
          });
  }

  self.getValue = function(key) {
    return DB.query("SELECT value FROM config WHERE key = '"+key+"'")
    .then(function(result){
              return DB.fetchOne(result);
          });
  };
  return self;
})
```

with the following code in controller.js under the heading:

```
.factory('DB', function($q, DB_CONFIG) {
        var self = this;
        self.db = null;
```

(I took the init part of the function away for the sake of simplicity. Also DB is working well when inserting, getting and updating data.)

```
self.fetchOne = function(result) {
  var output = null;
  output = angular.copy(result.rows.item(0));
  return output;
};

self.query = function (sql, bindings) {
    bindings = typeof bindings !== 'undefined' ? bindings : [];
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    self.db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(sql, bindings, function (transaction, result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function (transaction, error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
self.fetchAll = function (result) {
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        output.push(result.rows.item(i));
    }

    return output;
};
```

Called like so:

```
$scope.config.recordar = Config.getValue("recordar");
```

Doing a console.log returns:

[image: Chrome Console]

I am struggling to access the **value: "true"** which is highlighted in BLUE in the above image.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.config.recordar = Config.getValue("recordar");
```

Does not work (ala JS). It has to be called like so:

```
Config.getValue("recordar").then(function(data) {
$scope.config.recordar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you shall change your function declaration from :

```
  self.setValue = function(key,value) {
    console.log('setValue(value)', value);
    return DB.query("UPDATE config SET value = '"+value+"' WHERE key = '"+key+"'")
    .then(function(result){
              return DB.fetchAll(result);
          });
  }
```

to

```
  self.setValue = function(key,value) {
    console.log('setValue(value)', value);
    DB.query("UPDATE config SET value = '"+value+"' WHERE key = '"+key+"'")
    .then(function(result){
              return DB.fetchAll(result);
          });
  }
```

You will return the result of your promise, not your promise
I have changed "return DB..."  to "DB..."

Comment: Now Config.getValue("recordar") is undefined

Comment: can you please add the code of your controller that is calling the config.getValue

Comment: $scope.config.recordar = Config.getValue("recordar"); CONTROLLER HEADING: .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $state, Auth, Config) {

Comment: Don't know if it has an impact, but I personnaly initialise my factories with var self = {}; instead of var self = this. 
Can you please also add a "console.log("FACTORY START");" just after var selft ... This is to test that your factory is well injected.

Comment: Can you paste your full error message ? it looks strange that it is undefined.

Comment: There's no error message, but as $Config.getValue("recordar") is undefined in your example, I cannot use it. In my post the "error" is that I cannot figure out how to access the value in the promise.

Comment: One thing that is I see is that you're changing the setValue, when I am actually executing getValue. Initially seemed minor, but as I am still stuck in it might help :)

Comment: Added self.query and self.fetchAll